# Json data object in Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have created 3 `form` elements. Each form contains 8 text fields. If I click    the Submit button, the data I have entered in these text fields is converted into JSON format and finally posted into my database. I am using an AJAX post call. My code is:

```
<form id="xxx">8 text field code ...</form>
<form id="yyy">8 text field code ...</form>
<form id="zzz">8 text field code ...</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ifbuttonclick").click(function(e) {
            var jsonData = {};
            var form1 = $("#xxx").serializeArray(); //get form1 data
            var form2 = $("#yyy").serializeArray();
            var form3 = $("#zzz").serializeArray();
            var formData = {
                "form1": form1,
                "form2": form2,
                "form3": form3
            };

            console.log(formData); // working fine

            $.each(formData, function() {
                if (jsonData[this.name]) { //**here shows JsonData is Undefined**
                    if (!jsonData[this.name].push) {
                        jsonData[this.name] = [jsonData[this.name]];
                    }
                    jsonData[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                } else {
                    jsonData[this.name] = this.value || '';
                }
            });
            console.log(jsonData);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                beforeSend: function(request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "xxxxxxxxxxxx");
                },
                url: "...mydburl....",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: jsonData,
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $("#response").text("");
                    $("#response").append(data);
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        })
    })
</script>
```

Please correct my code. I want to know how to get 3 form's data into a single JSON object.If my approach wrong, please post any sample.How to achieve this?

Comment: what structure is api endpoint expecting?

Comment: that's structure is not valid

Comment: it's not about how ... it's about what the expected structure should be. You provided invalid object structure

Comment: Where i can change my code? or how to form my data structure in json format? can u explain anyother way?

Comment: Can map those serialized arrays to any structure you want and then convert to json string. You need to identify what that preferred structure is in order to do the mapping